# Need help in php associative array for replacing keys and value

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

this is output from array.

```
[25.1] => Super Cylinder|2080
[25.2] => Main Post Powered Rotation|10780
[36.1] => Electric H-Frame Trolley|16630
[36.2] => Air Powered H-Frame Trolley|11028
```

I want output like this how can I get this output.
How can set associated keys value into main key that will be round number.

```
[25]=> Super Cylinder|2080,Main Post Powered Rotation|10780
[36]= > Electric H-Frame Trolley|16630, Air Powered H-Frame
```

How Can I get the array values like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could merge it manually as:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    "25.1" => "Super Cylinder|2080",
    "25.2" => "Main Post Powered Rotation|10780",
    "36.1" => "Electric H-Frame Trolley|16630",
    "36.2" => "Air Powered H-Frame Trolley|11028"
);

$ret = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $key_new = intval($key);
    if(!isset($ret[$key_new])) $ret[$key_new] = array();
    array_push($ret[$key_new], $val);
}
//print_r($ret);

//merge the values
foreach($ret as $key => &$val){
    $val = implode(",", $val);
}
unset($val);
print_r($ret);

?>
```

this gives:

```
Array
(
    [25] => Super Cylinder|2080,Main Post Powered Rotation|10780
    [36] => Electric H-Frame Trolley|16630,Air Powered H-Frame Trolley|11028
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Short solution using regular `foreach` loop:

```
$arr = [
    "25.1" => "Super Cylinder|2080",
    "25.2" => "Main Post Powered Rotation|10780",
    "36.1" => "Electric H-Frame Trolley|16630",
    "36.2" => "Air Powered H-Frame Trolley|11028"
];

$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $rounded = round((int) $k);
    (isset($result[$rounded]))? $result[$rounded] .= ', '. $v : $result[$rounded] = $v;
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [25] => Super Cylinder|2080, Main Post Powered Rotation|10780
    [36] => Electric H-Frame Trolley|16630, Air Powered H-Frame Trolley|11028
)
```